# asp.net notifyIcon balloon tip popup with sound

Tags: asp.net, notifyicon, balloon

I am using `asp.net` `notifyIcon` Control for opening up Popup in status bar with `asp.net` windows. I also want to add sound to the popup but I am not able to add.

Is there any way to add a sound, for windows base application?

Comment: i just used following code and it works.. its will play just windows beep/ping sound
public void onePing()
        {
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }

Comment: What do you mean `asp.net notifyIcon` control? Do you show notify icon in windows taskbar from your page?

Comment: yes, i wanted to popup notification on windows staskbar

Comment: The next your question will be `why notifyIcon doesn't works when I deploy my web site`

Comment: i its done i got the things, will it create problem while doing deploy ?

Comment: No problem apart from that notification will be shown somewhere on server.